# Access old request sent to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, request, amazon-cloudfront

I need to check few requests that i had locally sent to cloudfront some time back. Does cloudfront stores any requests it receives or requests it sends?

Comment: You can enable [Access logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have enabled logs on your Cloud Front Distribution then you will not be able to get those requests as Cloud Front does not store any logs if they are not enabled. Try to search your local logs and you will have to guess which logs were used for Cloud Front.